# IE 7/8 not running .innerhtml = data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

The below code doesn't run in IE7/8. I researched online, `.innerhtml`  will not work in IE 7/8 Browser.  I really need this code to run in those browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/get_header",
      data: hashes,
      success: function(data) {
        if (!$.support.leadingWhitespace) {
          alert('j');
          document.getElementById('logo-bar').innerHTML = data;
        } else {
          $('#logo-bar').html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {}
    });
```

Comment: Yes. I want my code to display logo banner (#logi-bar) on page load. logo banner comes fine in ff and chrome but in IE 7 and 8 it doesn't load. The website is styletag.com, in IE the pop up doesn't show up.

Comment: when did a console.log(data) it shows the pop up banner code, but it doesn't render the pop up code in IE 7/8

Answer (score 3):

You're using jQuery for the AJAX request, so you may as well use it to update the DOM too. If you are concerned about leading whitespace in the response text, you can use `$.trim()` to remove it:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#logo-bar').html($.trim(data));
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this got upvoted - as there is no reason this would solve OP's issue - the code here wouldn't work where OP's `document.getElementById(..).innerHTML = ` wouldn't.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The OPs code may not work, as IE *still* has issues with innerHTML. See here for info: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html. jQuery contains work arounds for these problems.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Thanks. The above code is used to trigger the popup banner for the site. But $('#logo-bar').html(data); works in ff and chrome, in IE it hides the main nav bar and no pop up shows up. So used (!$.support.leadingWhitespace) to run the code only for IE

Comment: What is the content of `data`? It should work in IE too.

Comment: content is the page pertaining to the pop up image. This is the site am talking abt styletag.com